# How to assert on list of actual values and list of expected values ?(using java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, assertion

There are two training sections and in each section there is a set of fields (training name, country, training Institute, training From, training To). I want to assert these expected vs actual values using for loops.

How can I do this?

When I tried to write the code its displayed this error for me

```
expected [Training of Example] but found [Training of Sample],
expected [Training Institute of Example] but found [Training Institute of sample],
Start date mismatch expected [true] but found [false]
```

I was not expecting any assert failures.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. It looks like you have actual failures. We can't tell if they are legit or not because you haven't provided any info.